# Why doesn't SwiftUI's Text display tab space under some circumstances?

Tags: string, text, swiftui, tabs

For example, I have this string for `Text`: `Incoming event 0       111`.(There are two tab spaces between 0 and 111.)

When there is enough width space to show it,it is fine.

[image]

But if there isn't enough width space to show it in a single line, it wraps into two lines,and the tab spaces disappear magically(At least one of the tab spaces does,if not both of them).

[image]

Is this a bug or did I miss something?(It is a macOS App)

Answer (score 1):

It works fine if you code tab as `\t` in the string. Otherwise the tab key is translated into spaces, which will sometimes be ignored in line breaking.

[image]

```
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 30) {
            
            Text("Incoming event 0\t\t111")
                .frame(width: 300, alignment: .leading)
                .border(.red)
            
            Text("Incoming event 0\t\t111")
                .frame(width: 150, alignment: .leading)
                .border(.red)
        }
```

Comment: Because the text string comes from user input, I cann't find a way to put \t there. `replacingOccurrences(of: "\t",with: "\t")`,that seems nonsense :],any suggestions? Besides, seems like TextEditor handle tab space correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick check with user input and to me it seems like it's working fine ... isn't that the behavior you want?

[image]

```
            TextField("Input", text: $input)
            
            Text(input)
                .frame(width: 300, alignment: .leading)
                .border(.red)
            
            Text(input)
                .frame(width: 150, alignment: .leading)
                .border(.red)
```

Comment: Yes,that is what I want.Maybe it is a macOS specific problem?My App is running on macOS.